# Website not appear in the other network

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-6, iis-8

It is possible to register a domain name with the IP address of the wifi network to use it later in iis.

I've tried the website is only Displayed for computers  That Same are connected to the WiFi network does not Appear in the other network.

Answer (score 0):

It's POSSIBLE to do this, but why would you want to? Most WiFi "network" devices are Wireless Access Points and/or hubs that already have an embedded port80/443 web service. You would be pointing a domain to a pre-existing (and non-modifiable) host.

Can you be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: I've registered the domain name with wifi addresen ip 192.168.1.5.
website can appear only for users of wifi network.
the I also tried to open firewall port 80/443 but it is impossible to appear on other networks.
Can you give me a link or something like tuturial can do.
Thank you

Comment: 192.168.x.x is private address space and cannot be assigned to a registered host name. If you want internal computers to go there, you don't need to get a domain name. Simply update the hosts file (on windows) and put an entry into the file like this: 

192.168.1.5       myprivatewebdomain.com

Now all traffic on that machine will redirect to 192.168.1.5 for web calls to that domain.